# In a connected metric space, to prove $d(s,y)<\epsilon$, where $y\in B(a,r+\epsilon)\setminus B(a,r) $ and $s$ is some point in boundary of $B(a,r)$.

Tags: metric-spaces, connectedness

Let $(X,d)$ be a connected metric space, $B(a,r)$ denote an open ball centered at $a$ with radius $r$. Let $y\in B(a,r+\epsilon)\setminus B(a,r) $, for some $\epsilon>0$. How to prove that $d(s,y)<\epsilon$ for some $s$ in the boundary of $B(a,r)$, or how to disprove it (may be by giving some example)?

What I tried is:

In normed spaces, I found this is true. In case of connected metric space, we have boundary of $B(a,r)=\{s\in X:d(a,s)=r\}=S$, say; I tried to prove $d(a,y)= \sup\limits_{s\in S}d(a,s) + \sup\limits_{s\in S}d(s,y)$ or $d(a,y)= \inf\limits_{s\in S}d(a,s) + \inf\limits_{s\in S}d(s,y)$, but couldnot succeed.

Comment: The question has a positive answer if we make a small correction: *In a connected metric space, to prove $d(s,y)<\epsilon$, where $y\in B(a,r+\epsilon)\setminus B(a,r) $ and $s$ is some point in $S(a,r)=\{x\in X: d(x,a)=r\}$.*

Comment: In connected metric spcae, S(a,r)=the set of boundary points of B(a,r).

Comment: NOT TRUE. Set 
$$
X=\big\{(x,y)\in\mathbb R^2: x^2+y^2=1\big\}\cup \big(\mathbb R\times \{0\}\big).
$$
Then $X$ is a connected metric space, once endowed with the Euclidean distance of $\mathbb R^2$. But
$$
\partial B\big((0,0),1\big)=\{(-1,0),(1,0)\}, \quad\text{while}\quad
S\big((0,0),1\big)=\big\{(x,y)\in\mathbb R^2: x^2+y^2=1\big\}.
$$ Remember that $\partial A=\overline{A}\cap\overline{X\setminus A}$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $S=\left\{\langle x,y\rangle\in\Bbb R^2:x^2+y^2=1\text{ and }x\ne 1\right\}$, and let $X=\Bbb R\setminus S$ with the usual metric; because $\langle 1,0\rangle\in X$, $X$ is still connected. Let $a=\langle 0,0\rangle$ and $r=1$, and for any $\epsilon>0$ let $y=\left\langle -1-\frac{\epsilon}2,0\right\rangle$; then $y\in B(a,r+\epsilon)\setminus B(a,r)$, but the only point in the boundary of $B(a,r)$ is $\langle 1,0\rangle$, and $d(y,\langle 1,0\rangle)=2+\frac{\epsilon}2$, which is greater than or equal to $\epsilon$ whenever $\epsilon\le 4$.